# Magento 2.3 Composer stuck while downloading https://repo.magento.com/packages.json

Tags: magento2, error, composer, repository, download

I have a problem since about 24 hours I guess.
When I try to download Magento 2 with composer I stuck after logging with my user-credentials. The credentials are ok, it pass and go through the next step: Downloading https://repo.magento.com/packages.json

Here it hangs up. Nothing happens anymore.

I checked if the link is down, but its active.
I use the composer -vvv command what gives me a detailed view about what composer is doing. Here it stucks.

I've searched the web but could not find this error anywhere.

Has anybody faced the same strange thing?

I appreciate your help.

Thank you and have a great day.

Timm

Comment: Iv been using this all day not had this issue what so ever have you tried setting up a local version to see if it is an issue with your server